# XCode. A questions icon appears instead of app's UI elements

Tags: xcode, uikit, uitextfield, uilabel

First time in my life I've saw bug like this. I'll post 2 screenshots from my app. In first case the page looks like it has to and in the second case what get (some uikit elements like uilabel & uitextfield). Additional info, this bug happens not all the time, sometimes the page looks normal and sometimes not. Also it happens with all view controllers in the app. How to resolve the problem, does anybody met something like this?
XCode version: Version 11.5 (11E608c)
May be it could be important. This app isn't written as a new project, but copy/paste from older project with changing bundle id.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does your app support localization? Also, were you able to catch the issue with a breakpoint and see what strings get assigned to the UI elements that get their texts dynamically in the code?

Comment: Yes, I have localization in the app. I thought it happens because of font file...